# What part did the kids' uncle play in Narnia?

Tags: the-chronicles-of-narnia

It's not exactly in my mind, but when the kids returned from Narnia, they said something like "you won't believe it" to their uncle. But, the uncle (the owner of the mansion) did not seem surprised, leading me to believe that he had experienced it before (probably, when he was kid).

In Narnia, there was a prophecy that the kids would come to rule the world. What parts were the uncle fit in?

Comment: He wasn't their uncle; he was the owner of the house that they had been evacuated to.

Comment: The answer to both of your recent questions is: Read *The Magician's Nephew*. :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This man is Digory Kirke, and while I don't believe it's been specified in the movie universe, in the original novels Digory is one of two protagonists in the first Narnia novel (chronologically), *The Magician's Nephew*.

As a child he and Polly end up in Narnia, and are two of the first, if not **the** first humans to do so. They witness Aslan creating the land.

They, if my memory serves, are also responsible for bringing the White Witch, called Jadis here, into Narnia, as well as Frank the cab driver (who is made the First King of Narnia) and his cab horse, who becomes a talking animal.

Though published sixth in the series, this novel is chronologically first (as a prequel) and explains things such as the lamppost in Narnia; and in some collections is presented first.

As DavidS points out (thanks muchly), the children take an apple with them from Narnia back to Earth, which is planted (along with, as MartianInvader pointed out [ta!], the magic world-hopping rings that give the wood a magical nature) and grows into a tree, from which this wardrobe is created (This is very much a "this is why" installment to the series).

In addition (and we're sliding a tad away from the point here), earlier in the movie the other children complain about Lucy's stories to Uncle Digory, who in so many words tells them they should be more believing, and (I believe) outright saying that *he* believes her.

Digory's story is very much internal. His mother is sick, dying. He brings the witch to Narnia by mistake and Aslan gives him a quest to atone for it. The witch tries to persuade him to steal a magic apple which can grant him immortality, or heal his mother (she also tries to make him abandon Polly). He doesn't, thankfully since the magic is your standard tricksy be careful what you wish for stuff. As thanks Aslan gives him a new apple which **does** heal his mother, and then he uses the seeds to plant the tree.

However, because of his actions humans came to Narnia and a portal was made between our world and Narnia. He didn't do much of importance during his brief stay, but because of his actions a human was there to be made king, and his actions also provide Lucy, Edmund, Susan and Peter a way to get into Narnia

Comment: Might want to add that their adventure brings an apple from Narnia into our world, which becomes a tree, which is made into the wardrobe from The Lion, The Witch, And the Wardrobe.

Comment: Did Digory serve any special purpose in Narnia?

Comment: [Wikipedia says it was published **sixth**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia#Publication_history)

Comment: @AakashM woops! Ta :)

Comment: I'm not sure they were asking for the entire plot of The Magician's Nephew but good answer.

Comment: One more point: Digory travelled through worlds using magic rings, and at the end of the book buries these rings with the apple seeds.  It's further explanation for where the wood got its "world-hopping" powers from.

Comment: The plot explanation, to clarify, only touches on the major points (I skipped over a whole load of really cool adventure narrative) and was *supposed* to address "Did Digory serve any special purpose in Narnia?", but it may have gotten away from me a tad.

Comment: @MartianInvader I'd forgotten about that! Nice.

Comment: Personally, this was my favorite book of the series.

Comment: 'They, if my memory serves, are also responsible for bringing the White Witch, called Jadis here, into Narnia, as well as Frank the cab driver (who is made the First King of Narnia) and his cab horse, who becomes a talking animal.' That's quite correct indeed. And iirc there is something about Jadis and the lamp post; perhaps throwing it? But he wasn't their uncle; he just happened to own the house in the country they went to during the war (which the film elaborates on by adding a scene of the Luftwaffe dropping bombs on their house). He's indirectly responsible for the gateway of course.